# JUnit test throwing errors while using when then

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a JUnit test as posted below but it throws `InvalidUseOfMatchers` error on `when().then()`. I tried to replace it with:

```
when(any(MyUtilityClass.class).inheritedMethod(anyMap(), anyString())).thenReturn(anyString());
```

But then it throws `NullPointer`. So, how can I resolve this isssue?

**MyUtilityClassTest**

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class MyUtilityClassTest {
    
        @InjectMocks
        private MyUtilityClass muc;
        
        @Test
        void test() {
            when(muc.inheritedMethod(anyMap(), anyString())).thenReturn(anyString()); //invalid use of matchers error
            var response = muc.getData();
            assertEquals("EXPECTED_VALUE", response.getValue());
        }
    }
```

**MyUtilityClass**

```
public MyUtilityClass extends AbstractParentClass {
    
    @Value("${value}")
    private String value;

    public DataClass getData() {
        var data = DataClass.builder().build();
        data.setValue( inheritedMethod(new HashMap<String, Object>(), value) );
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mock statement is with muc. But muc is not mock object it is InjectedMock. To mock a class @Mock or @Spy is used. But mock object is used when you have dependency of other class. but as per your code you are testing MyUtilityClass and its seems that inheritedMethod is also in the same class. I think You don't need to mock anything unless you have dependency of other class.